# Deleting All Rows That Have A Certain Value For One Column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 45 columns and 13970 rows. I want to delete all of the rows that have a 0 value for one of the columns.

I have tried subset(dataframe, column!=0) 
and 
dataframe[!dataframe$column == 0, ]

but neither of these work. When I use the subset function, it also deletes all of the rows that have NA for this column, but I need to retain those rows.

How can I delete all the rows that have a 0 in just one particular column?

Comment: Your method should work.  Check if you have a `factor` column or `character` with spaces leading/lagging etc?  One way to test is `subset(dataframe, trimws(column) !="0")`

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference between dataframe[!apply(dataframe==0, 1, any),] and dataframe[!dataframe$column==0, ] is?

I figured out the "0" wasn't working because it isn't text.

Comment: When I use subset(dataframe,column!=0) it removes all of the rows with 0 in this column, but it also removes all of the rows with NA for the column.

Comment: How about `dataframe[-which(dataframe$column == 0), ]` ?

Comment: @user3 The documentation of `subset()` says: **For ordinary vectors, the result is simply x[subset & !is.na(subset)].** From your comment I read that you want in the result the rows, where NA is in that column, right?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep rows that have NA for this column and all other values except for 0.

dataframe[-which(dataframe$column == 0), ] worked! Thank you @ikop!!

And thank you everyone for helping so quickly!

Comment: `dataframe[is.na(dataframe$column) | dataframe$column!=0,]`

Comment: Awesome this worked too, thank you @jogo